# Not able to fetch records from apache solr

Tags: apache, solr

I'am using Apache Solr 7.5  in Cloud mode with 2 shard and 2 replica in a single node.

when I give

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/Transactions_new/select?q=*:*

I get the response as below

```
response":{"numFound":10257992,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs"
```

but when I give as the below  query

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/Transactions_new/select?q=*:*&rows=100&start=10257000

I don't find any records in it. What might be the problem?

Comment: What is your layout? Do you have multiple servers or a single node? Are you using any kind of sharding? What does numFound say when you use the large `start` value?

Comment: added clarity to the question

Comment: This can be caused by duplicate ids between shards - that issue won't be shown before iteration of the document set actually happens. Does the numFound value change when trying to retrieve the last documents? Have you tried comparing the file size and md5sum of the index files on the different nodes?